# Android Device can't find Shared Library

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I'm working on a Android NDK Project. I've build an .so-File names receivetest.so . My app is loading this code with

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("receivetest");
}
```

If i let my App run on a Virtual Device via Eclipse it's working fine. But when im starting the same .apk File on my "real" Device i get the error

```
"Couldn't load receivetest:findLibrary returned null"
```

I've allready searched in the .apk file and it contains a folder lib which contains the receivetest.so . This error seems a little weird for me. Maybe someone of you allready had the same experience and can help me.

Comment: do you have libreceivetest.so inside libs/armeabi ?

Comment: yes,my .apk-file contains the folder lib/armeabi/receivetest.so

Comment: it has to call libreceivetest.so not receivetest.so

Comment: yes, that solved the problem

Comment: @blackbelt would you create an answer from your comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be loaded corretly your library has to be called  `libreceivetest.so` and it has to be placed inside the folder `libs/armeabi`